# Return the control of a function in C

Tags: c, function, reverse-engineering, parent, ida

How to make a return of C function returned directly to the grandparent function, not to the parent one? in reverse engineering. 
For example, I have 3 functions (main, f1, and f2) 
the main called f1, and the f1 called f2..
I want to return the f2 directly to the main without passing through p1.

Comment: that is very dangerous, how to be sure of the call tree ? It is very much sure and simple to return from f2 with a given value check in f1 to return from it

Comment: Are you looking for `setjmp`/`longjmp`?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: how does `p1()` factor into your question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a tool like `ida`, you should just be able to set the program counter directly to what you want (from the grandparents stack frame when it called the parent).

In other words, make a note of what gets pushed on the stack as the return address when the grandparent executes `call parent`, and then load that value if and when you want to return to it.

Just be aware that you may be skipping code that's vital for some downstream action. But I assume, if you're reverse engineering, you know enough to look out for things like that :-)